# Quick question on Pauli matrices and u(2)

Tags: representation-theory

The wiki page for Pauli matrices states

"Together with the 2 × 2 identity matrix I (sometimes written as σ0), the Pauli matrices form an orthogonal basis, in the sense of Hilbert–Schmidt, for the real Hilbert space of 2 × 2 complex Hermitian matrices, or the complex Hilbert space of all 2 × 2 matrices. "

Is the second assertion just flat out wrong?

Clear Identity and Paulis span u(2) as a real vector space which is the first assertion (4 real dimensions). But the complex Hilbert space of all 2 × 2 matrices is 8 (real) dimensional!?

Comment: The four complex coefficients of the Pauli matrices provide in total 8 real degrees of freedom, which matches the number of degrees of freedom in the complex $2x2$ matrix.

Comment: ok so the complex span, I guess I found the language confusing